# How to properly use jquery prev?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How to select the previous element using [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)? I want when I click `icon 1` it removes the `span`.

**html.erb**

```
# inside a loop -- notice the loop!.
<span data-id="foo_span">
  <i data-id="bar">icon 1</i>
  <i>icon 2</i>
</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("[data-id=bar]").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //$(this).prev("[data-id=foo_span]").remove();
  $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Am I using `prev()` correctly? Based on the examples, it uses `.css`. What's the correct method to remove the span tag? `i` must be inside a span tag.

Comment: `prev()` is going backwards in the *siblings* collection. You need to use `parent()` instead.

Comment: prev() is sibling... Please read the documentation https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: @epascarello Sometimes when your brain is tired, nothing makes sense lol but I have re-read it and now I understand. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method and **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** method is using to get the immediately preceding sibling of the element.

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

Comment: Oh my days! I was digging around last night and saw that somewhere but it never clicked. Yes that worked!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/ndva0rkz/

```
$("body").on("click", ".f", function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  //$(this).prev("[data-id=foo_span]").remove();
  $(this).prev().remove();
});
<span data-id="foo_span">
  <i class="f" data-id="bar">icon 1</i>
  <i class="f">icon 2</icon>
</span>
```

Comment: For me, it removes the complete loop.

Comment: I tried to keep 'prev' in the code to show usage. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using parent() ?

```
$("[data-id=bar]").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```